# How do I display a scrolling div (or other container) on a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am currently writing a Terms and Conditions page for a wireless hotspot captive portal.

I want to display the length Ts and Cs in a div and let the user scroll through them if they desire.

Easy enough for non-mobile browsers:

```
 <div id="terms" data-theme="a" style="overflow: scroll; height: 200px;">
      <p>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Terms)</p>
 </div>
```

When I view the page on my mobile device, I get a div that feels like `overflow: hidden` and no scrolling. I've read that two finger scrolling works on iOS devices, but I need Android to work as well.

I'm using the newly released [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/) framework.

An alternate solution that would be agreeable to me is some kind of scrolling dialog box I could pop, but it seems like I would still have the same problem. I'm open to ideas.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4); works on mobile + desktop and doesn't conflict with JQM.

Has the added bonus of having the feel of a mobile browser scroll.

Answer (score 0):

jQM Offer some experimental options:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

I think you might look into:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html

Comment: @JayDave Yeah those are really old, you might have some luck digging around the branches: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/